# What's the purpose of this block on apache virtualhost?

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

Often times, many people using this configuration on their Apache virtual host.

```
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/website/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

I was wondering, what's the use of following block? Why are there root path `/` specified here?

```
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Is this some security measure to apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` means the root directory.

Read about
 [Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory):

> If multiple (non-regular expression)  sections match the
> directory (or one of its parents) containing a document, then the
> directives are applied in the order of shortest match first,
> interspersed with the directives from the .htaccess files. For
> example, with
>
> ```
> <Directory "/">
>   AllowOverride None
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/home">
>   AllowOverride FileInfo
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> for access to the document /home/web/dir/doc.html the steps are:
>
> - Apply directive AllowOverride None (disabling .htaccess files).
> - Apply directive AllowOverride FileInfo (for directory /home).
> - Apply any FileInfo directives in /home/.htaccess, /home/web/.htaccess and /home/web/dir/.htaccess in that order.